# Unable to include Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm including Firebase AuthUI library in my android app. The code for including that dependency is `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.2.0'`

There is an error when I sync which says: `Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1`

I'm trying include `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'` but the same error is showing up again.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: change firebaseui to 1.2.0 and contraint to 1.0.1

Comment: Now it says `Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0`

Comment: Because you must change all version. Click on the red bulb to see what it suggests

Comment: this twitter thing is not going away no matter what I try... Shall I try decreasing the version even more?

Comment: Yes, you can try

Comment: It is working if I use an older version (0.6.0). Are there any disadvantages in using an older version ?

Comment: I think you do not have all the features

Answer (score 0):

At your gradle build file update the dependencies to

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

and at toy gradle project level at this to your repositories

```
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

To be like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```